# Rails :An attribute seen inside all the actions of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can i create an attribute in a controller class, that can be seen inside all the actions and all the view related to this controller?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `instance variable` in your Controller and make sure to give an `attr_accessor` to that variable so that it will be accessible to all your views.

Answer (score 0):

Create before filter in your controller

**For Example:**

before_filter :example

def example

@variable = true

end

Now **@variable** is accessible in every action as well as views